# Still getting nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object, even when controller is supposed to redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in common_apps/show, I write an if/else statement that checks if the user has a 'common_app', and if they don't, I redirect them.

In the corresponding common_apps/show view, I just render the common_app.

However, in the case where the user should be redirected, rails is producing the error

```
nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object. It must implement :to_partial_path.
```

The reason this is happening because @common_app will be nil, if the user does not have a common_app. However, in the common_app controller I do have the if/else statement, so if the common_app is nil, then it should redirect to a different page.

How should I write this so that in the case where a user has no common_app, they are redirected, rather than seeing a nil error?

This is my show definition in the controller :

```
  def show
    if current_user.common_app.present?
      redirect_to new_common_app, notice: "Looks like you haven't made your common application. Fill it in below."
    else
      @common_app = current_user.common_app
    end
  end
```

This is my show view :

```
<% provide(:title, current_user.name) %>
<h1><%= current_user.name %></h1>

<ul>
    <%= render @common_app %>
</ul>
```

Comment: I mean you could render any partial or file, not variable. Here @common_app is a variable

Comment: [stepan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1292663/stepan-parunashvili) is your problem solved..? If yes then why you are not giving credit to contributors who are wasting their time to help you

Comment: Hi Mihir, what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic on the if condition is the wrong way round.  Can be better written as:

```
def show
  @common_app = current_user.common_app
  redirect_to new_common_app_path, notice: "Looks like you haven't made your common application. Fill it in below." unless @common_app.present?
end
```

Comment: Thanks dmc! Just so I learn, what was I doing that was screwing things up? The way you wrote it is compact and works excellently, but if @common_app is nil in this scenario, shouldn't it do the same thing?

Comment: common_app was nil, as the logic was incorrect you were rendering the template and not redirecting as intended.  Rails tried to infer the partial which it couldn't do due to common app being nil.

Answer (score 1):

in your show action why not change to if current_user.common_app.nil? or even if !current_user.common_app

Answer (score 1):

You could do this way if you want to use your @common_app varible in your partial

```
<%= render partial: "name_of_partial", locals: {common_app: @common_app} %>
```